# cmake dependency not trigged

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I try to use cmake in my project (actually move from make to cmake). I bump into a problem that I can't solve. I try to streamline my architecture like this (hope this is not too streamlined). I use ld -r here as an example custom command that produce files and intermediate files.

Here is my file structure.

```
.
`-- libs
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- l1
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- l1_f1.c
    |   `-- l1_f2.c
    `-- l2
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- l2_f1.c
        `-- l2_f2.c
```

The .c files

```
./libs/l1/l1_f1.c::
#include <stdio.h>
int v1;
int l1_f1(){ printf("In l1_f1()\n");}

./libs/l1/l1_f2.c::
#include <stdio.h>
int l1_f2(){ printf("In l1_f2()\n");}

./libs/l2/l2_f1.c::
#include <stdio.h>
int l2_f1(){ printf("In l2_f1()\n");}

./libs/l2/l2_f2.c::
#include <stdio.h>
int l2_f2(){ printf("In l2_f2()\n");}
```

And my CMakeLists.txt files

```
./libs/CMakeLists.txt::
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PL VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(../libs/l1 libs/l1)
add_subdirectory(../libs/l2 libs/l2)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l.a
COMMAND ld -r  libs/l1/l1.o  libs/l2/l2.o -o l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.a
COMMAND ar r l.a l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.o
DEPENDS L1 L2
)

add_custom_target(
LA
ALL
DEPENDS l.a
)

./libs/l1/CMakeLists.txt::
add_library(l1 OBJECT l1_f1.c l1_f2.c)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l1.o
COMMAND ld -r $<TARGET_OBJECTS:l1> -o l1.o
DEPENDS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:l1>
COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)

add_custom_target(
L1
ALL
DEPENDS l1.o
)

./libs/l2/CMakeLists.txt::
add_library(l2 OBJECT l2_f1.c l2_f2.c)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l2.o
COMMAND ld -r $<TARGET_OBJECTS:l2> -o l2.o
DEPENDS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:l2>
COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)

add_custom_target(
L2
ALL
DEPENDS l2.o
)
```

Now the question

I run the original cmake like this

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G Ninja ../libs && ninja

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/phi/p2/build
[7/7] Generating l.a
ar: creating l.a
```

I am happy with that l.a is created and doing a nm(1) on it shows the v1 global variable.

```
nm l.a

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1
```

Now the problem, I touch 1 file l1_f1.c and rebuild

```
VY$ sed -i 's/v1/v2/' ../libs/l1/l1_f1.c

VY$ ninja
[2/2] Generating l1.o
```

As we see here l.a is not rebuild, despite I thought I made a dep for regen it. Obvioulsy I must be wrong, I am new to cmake.

The nm(1) confirm l.a is not regened.

```
VY$ nm l.a libs/l1/l1.o

l.a:

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1

libs/l1/l1.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2
```

Can someone enlight me how I could get l.a regened ?

Thanx in advance, cheers.

---

### The following is added after Tsyvarev answer proposition.

1) Adding file-level dependencies in main CMakeLists.txt prevent initial build. Note that your initial line `DEPENDS libs/l1/l1.o libs/l1/l2.o` generate an error as it look file in the source tree instead of the build tree so I changed it to `DEPENDS ../build/libs/l1/l1.o ../build/libs/l2/l2.o`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PL VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(../libs/l1 libs/l1)
add_subdirectory(../libs/l2 libs/l2)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l.a
COMMAND ld -r  libs/l1/l1.o  libs/l2/l2.o -o l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.a
COMMAND ar r l.a l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.o

DEPENDS ../build/libs/l1/l1.o ../build/libs/l2/l2.o
DEPENDS L1 L2  
)

add_custom_target(
LA
ALL
DEPENDS l.a 
)
```

This give the following output on initial build

```
VY$ cd .. && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G Ninja ../libs && ninja


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
... [removed output]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/phi/p2/build
ninja: error: '/home/phi/p2/build/libs/l1/l1.o', needed by 'l.a', missing and no known rule to make it
```

2) rebuilding the project without the file-level dep.
    VY$ cd .. && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G Ninja ../libs && ninja

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
... [removed output]     
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/phi/p2/build
[7/7] Generating l.a
ar: creating l.a
```

3) With this initial build and your file-dep added again in the CMakethen ask for a partial rebuild give this

Initial setup after project build.

```
VY$ ninja;nm libs/l1/CMakeFiles/l1.dir/l1_f1.c.o ; nm l.a
ninja: no work to do.
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1
```

So this is v1, touching 1 file to make v2 and rebuild with  your file-level dep

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PL VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(../libs/l1 libs/l1)
add_subdirectory(../libs/l2 libs/l2)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l.a
COMMAND ld -r  libs/l1/l1.o  libs/l2/l2.o -o l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.a
COMMAND ar r l.a l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.o

DEPENDS ../build/libs/l1/l1.o ../build/libs/l2/l2.o
DEPENDS L1 L2  
)

add_custom_target(
LA
ALL
DEPENDS l.a 
)
```

give this

```
VY$ ninja
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/phi/p2/build
[2/2] Generating l1.o

VY$ nm libs/l1/CMakeFiles/l1.dir/l1_f1.c.o ; nm l.a
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1

VY$ ninja
[1/1] Generating l.a
ar: creating l.a

VY$ nm libs/l1/CMakeFiles/l1.dir/l1_f1.c.o ; nm l.a
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2
```

As we see here, on first ninja we got a cmake rebuild because I added back the file-level dep. Then only the l1.o is rebuild not l.o then l.a.

Second ninja trig the l.a rebuild.

It sounds like make basic dependencies actiopn rule is pretty magic with cmake, hope someone could help me here.

Cheers.

---

### The following is added after Tsyvarev latest comment.

The final fix from Tsyvarev make it working, need the set_source_files_propoerties()

The top CMakeLists.txt now look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PL VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(../libs/l1 libs/l1)
add_subdirectory(../libs/l2 libs/l2)

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT l.a
COMMAND ld -r ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l1/l1.o
              ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l2/l2.o  -o l.o
COMMAND rm -f l.a
COMMAND ar r l.a l.o 
COMMAND rm -f l.o

DEPENDS # Use absolute paths for files for prevent confusion
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l1/l1.o 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l2/l2.o
        # Target-level dependencies are needed too
        L1 L2
)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l1/l1.o 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l2/l2.o
    PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE
)

add_custom_target(
LA
ALL
DEPENDS l.a
)
```

And the builds, full and partial, gives the correct answer.

```
VY$ cd .. && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G Ninja ../libs && ninja


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/phi/p2/build
[7/7] Generating l.a
ar: creating l.a

VY$ ninja;nm libs/l1/CMakeFiles/l1.dir/l1_f1.c.o ; nm l.a
ninja: no work to do.
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v1

VY$ sed -i 's/v1/v2/' ../libs/l1/l1_f1.c

VY$ ninja;nm libs/l1/CMakeFiles/l1.dir/l1_f1.c.o ; nm l.a
[3/3] Generating l.a
ar: creating l.a
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2

l.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T l1_f1
0000000000000013 T l1_f2
0000000000000026 T l2_f1
0000000000000039 T l2_f2
                 U puts
0000000000000004 C v2
```

Comment: Any reason for using custom targets instead of `add_executable`/`add_library`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to perform compile/link steps manually, when CMake commands handle all of this messiness *for you*. I suggest spending some time with the CMake [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html). You can use `add_library()`/`add_executable()`, then `target_link_libraries()` for *linking*...

Comment: There are 2 reasons I used this example, 1) is to learn how cmake handle dependencies and trig actions, 2) this setup ressemble some need I have in a huge project migration from make to cmake (if doable) where many 'kinda' sublibs are build through ld -r, and final big one is done through a final ld -r then an ar(1) on the final .o may look strange but that exist. I should precise I work on unix/linux only with no port to MS/android. I know cmake handle cc/ld well but what I want to achieve is a bit more complex than that. I just need to know how to trig the final ld -r. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we see here `l.a` is not rebuild, despite I thought I made a dep for regen it.

You don't actually make `l.a` dependent from `l1.o` and other object files.

The line

```
DEPENDS L1 L2
```

in the custom command which creates `l.a` means only dependencies between the **target** `LA` (the target which depends from `l.a`) and the **targets** `L1` and `L2`. This is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/add_custom_command.html) for the `add_custom_command`. But your custom command itself doesn't have a dependency from `l1.o` **file** which you need.

The dependency between the *targets* forces only `LA` target to be built after `L1` and `L2`.

Correct way is to specify for `add_custom_command` **file**-level dependencies.

But, as dependency files are created in **other** `CMakeLists.txt`, additional steps are required:

1. **Target**-level dependencies. It involves targets which produces dependency files.
2. Marking the dependency files as `GENERATED`. Otherwise CMake would treat these files as already existed on *configuration* stage.

In result:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT l.a
    COMMAND ld -r  libs/l1/l1.o  libs/l2/l2.o -o l.o
    COMMAND rm -f l.a
    COMMAND ar r l.a l.o
    COMMAND rm -f l.o
    DEPENDS
        # Use absolute paths for files for prevent confusion
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l1/l1.o 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l2/l2.o
        # Target-level dependencies are needed too
        L1 L2
)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l1/l1.o 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/l2/l2.o
    PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE
)
```

---

The rationale behind needs to specify **file**-level dependencies even if you have **target**-level ones is that generally CMake has no notion about OUTPUT file for the target. Such notion exists only for targets create by `add_executable` or `add_library`, and in this case `DEPENDS` from such target actually enriches custom command with both **target**-level and **file**-level dependencies.

Comment: Thanx Tsyvarev, it doesn't answer, nothing works better with your answer, yet you pointed to some vocabulary about target-level vs file-level dependencies. Setting file-level dep as you did prevent the initial build to work, then if initial build setup then subsequent build require 2 ninja run to get the full rebuild. May be I should not use cmake for this kind of usage?

Comment: I'll edit my question to add your proposed change and why it doesn't work

Comment: I forgot about setting GENERATED property for the dependent files. And about preferring to use absolute paths for DEPEND files. Now the answer should work.

Comment: Thanx Tsyvarev, set_source_files_properties() was the missing bit from my learning curve. I did play a bit this morning with it, but never succeed to make it right. I used this link to converge to your solution that still have typos. I generalized the BIN DIR usage, in ld -r too, your typo is second BIN DIR is /l2/l2.o not /l1/l2.o, and the final type is TRUE missing after PROP GENED... I'll fix my question to reflect this. I bumped the answer +1 back along with the solved check. Thanx again.

Comment: The link Iused to help was https://samthursfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/cmake-dependencies-between-targets-and-files-and-custom-commands/